# Enable rendering asciidoc operation in InteliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, asciidoc, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

Documenting rest api using spring-restdocs in InteliJ Idea is fine, but I missing rendered "include" snippets of *operation* macro.

```
== Get Comments sorted

To get sorted according single attribute and with no specific ordering (asc-ending is default), you can refer to this example:

operation::comments/getSortedDescending[snippets='http-request,path-parameters,http-response']
```

I would expect that somehow I can enable spring-restdocs-asciidoc artefact to be used when rendering things in InteliJ Idea with asciidoctor plugin.

Associated issue https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-intellij-plugin/issues/310

Comment: You may contact plugin vendor: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7391-asciidoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look at spring-restdocs-asciidoctor. [The `operation::[]` is an extension](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/master/spring-restdocs-asciidoctor-support/src/main/resources/extensions/operation_block_macro.rb) that renders the content. It relies on an attribute `snippets` that needs to be set.

The IntelliJ plugin for AsciiDoc supports both [ruby extensions](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-intellij-plugin/wiki/Support-for-Asciidoctor-Extensions) and [attributes for previews](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-intellij-plugin/wiki/Support-project-specific-configurations) as experimental options.

To make it work I did the following:

- checkout the project
- running `gradlew asciidoctor` to generate the snippets
- add a file `.asciidoctorconfig` to set the path to the generated snippets
- add a directory `.asciidoctor` and place the extension in this directory
- confirm the warning message "This project contains Asciidoctor Extensions..." in the IDE

You need to confirm the warning message every time you restart your IDE. As it will run Ruby code locally, this is a security issue. Maybe we'll enhance it in the future so you only need to reconfirm it once the extension's code changes.

The changes are on the following branch: https://github.com/ahus1/spring-restdocs/tree/poc_extension_intellij

Comment: It also supports Java extensions and you have to copy the JAR files to `.asciidoctor/lib`. During the last weekend I was playing around with that to integrated Jamal pre-processing into IntelliJ Asciidoc plugin and it works fine.